# How do I "cool" down very spicy tortilla soup?

Tags: soup

Thought the recipe asked for a full can of chipolte peppers, of course it was only one. was able to remove most but is still to spicy for company.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, there are two ways to reduce how spicy any soup is:

- Make more soup and dilute the spices
- Add [more starch and/or dairy](https://healthyeating.sfgate.com/neutralize-spicy-foods-8179.html) to the existing soup

However, in your case, where you added about 8X as many peppers as you should have, I'm not sure either avenue is practical; you would have to at least triple the volume of the soup to have an effect.  I suggest starting over.

Comment: Saving the current batch as a "starter" that can be added to the new soup in small quantities could work. Especially if the soup freezes well.